# Sorting files in a list by mtime, fails to find files in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script which will automatically move my scanned lecture notes from specific dates to a folder.

To do this I need to sort the files on order of their upload date, which is their `mdate`.

The problem I am having is that the script does find the files and puts them in a `list`, but the `os.path.mtime()` command fails to find those same files.

Here is my code:

```
import os
p="someDir"
if os.path.isdir(p):
    files = os.listdir(p)
    print("Files found in folder:", files)
    files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Files found in folder: ['20180907.pdf', '20180831.pdf',
'20180905.pdf', '20180906.pdf']

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mats/Google Drive/Programmering/Python/Python 
Projects/homework/homework.py", line 32, in <module>
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20180907.pdf'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]! You can make the code parts of your question look nice by enclosing it in backticks (`). Also you should make the code so that we can actually run it with minimal effort: This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into solving the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you really are asking. I've suggested for edits in your question that fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable files contains:

```
['20180907.pdf', '20180831.pdf',
 '20180905.pdf', '20180906.pdf']
```

Which is not the path in absolute/relative in regards to the working directory. The path also includes the folder!

2 solutions: 1 you sort the list containing the path names, i.e:

```
from os.path import join
files = [join(p, elt) for elt in files]
```

Or you change the working directory in the loop, i.e. instead of the print:

```
os.chdir(p)
```

Comment: I tried changing the working directory:

        if os.path.isdir(p):
        os.chdir(p)
        files = os.listdir(os.curdir)
        print("Files found in folder:", files)
        files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)

which gave me this error:

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Anteckningar/20180831.pdf'

Comment: @Mats Without the possibility to test it, that's the most I can do. You need to figure out yourself. The error clearly states that the path passed to `os.path.getmtime` does not exist. Try to print it first, with a loop on the files. Maybe you'll spot your msitake. And remember that this path must be define relatively to the working directory define by `os.chdir()`.

Comment: I am sorry, turns out I am an idiot, your solution worked but that lead to some other issues further down the line, all I had to do was change the working directory back to os.pardir after sorting the files, thanks for your help